# Anchor containing an image takes full page width

Tags: html, css

On [my website](http://blurrapp.com), at the bottom with the "Download on the App Store" button, the button's link can be clicked from the full width of the page within the height of the button. I don't see anything in the HTML or CSS that is causing this:

```
    <div class="download">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/download-on-appstore.png" alt="Download on App Store"></a>
    </div>
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your css, you have this:

```
.app-details .download img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

img is set to display block, which consumes all available space.

Comment: But if I had it inline, how would I center it?

Comment: text-align:center on the download div will center the image wrapped in href

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct... to fix it however:

Remove the `display:block` from the img and make the `.apps-details .download` css this:

```
.app-details .download {
     background: url("../images/letters-bg.png") no-repeat;
     background-position: 57% 10%;
     padding: 150px 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
}
```